# How can I get the number of lines containing Chinese characters?

Tags: regex, bash, unicode, grep, cjk

I have a very big plain text file with all kinds of languages, such as English, Japanese, Chinese... I want to get the number of lines containing Chinese characters.

I think this can be done using grep and wc -l, but how can I actually do this job?

```
cat filename | grep -P "[\x{4e00}-\x{9fcc}]" | wc -l
```

This command does not work, and has this error message:

.grep: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large.

Comment: What kind of grep do you use (`grep -V`)?

Comment: You don't have to cat into GREP.  You can just use `grep -opt "pattern" filename`.  Not super helpful, I know.  but a tweak.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Python, you can observe what characters are used in the file with the help of the `unicodedata` module. Example with nāgarī input and Python 3:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> word = "ब्र॑ह्मन्"
>>> len(word)
9
>>> for char in word:
...     unicodedata.name(char)
... 
'DEVANAGARI LETTER BA'
'DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA'
'DEVANAGARI LETTER RA'
'DEVANAGARI STRESS SIGN UDATTA'
'DEVANAGARI LETTER HA'
'DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA'
'DEVANAGARI LETTER MA'
'DEVANAGARI LETTER NA'
'DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA'
```

Of course, you first need to look for the unicode names of the glyphs used in each script. A table of the unicode chars can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt). Some specific tables, for each language, are given on the same website.

Once you've defined the range of characters you want to catch, the rest is pretty easy:

```
all_chars = ['ब', '्', 'र', '॑', 'ह', '्','म', 'न', '्']

i = 0
with open('thefile') as f:
    for line in f.readline():
        i += 1
        for char in all_chars:
            if char in line:
                print("char %s found in line %s" % (char, i))
                continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're specifying the `-P` option, you're probably using GNU grep. The error message seems to come from PCRE, the Perl-compatible regular expression library. So <s>either your version of PCRE isn't Perl-compatible enough or</s> GNU grep doesn't use PCRE's Unicode features.

I'd simply try to run Perl directly:

```
perl -ne 'print if /[\x{4e00}-\x{9fcc}]/' filename | wc -l
```

**Edit:** I could test this on a Linux system today, and I found that it's probably caused by [this bug in grep](http://savannah.gnu.org/patch/?3934) (PCRE_UTF8 isn't set for UTF-8 locales) which has been fixed in [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=grep.git;a=commitdiff;h=67436786c110bbb565f0c1b96f1ca1d4586e1c8d;hp=c1996dd3c98a81cf700ba11e1521ca3d964aeabe). There's no official release with the fix yet but it should be included in the next release (2.15).